# No funciona página de error 404 en PHP usando Nginx

Tags: php, nginx

Tengo un servidor con Nginx y a la hora de crear una página error 404 tengo una duda. Lo tengo configurado de este modo:

```
 location / {
 try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
 error_page 405 = $uri;
 }
 error_page  404 /404.php;
```

Pero claro, esto solo funciona si la página que buscan tiene la extensión `.php`, si no lleva la extensión me salta el error 404 de nginx.

¿Qué puedo estar haciendo mal?

Comment: ¿Tienes un rato para revisar esto?

Comment: ¿Podrías describir un poco mejor qué ocurre con los mensajes de error según la URL? ¿Dices que si tienes extensión `.php` funciona correctamente la página de error pero si no la tiene falla? ¿Tienes algo más configurado en ese servidor virtual? Tal y como lo tienes configurado, si estás usando `php-fpm` tal y como recomienda la configuración por defecto de nginx, debería funcionarte todo correctamente. Quizá el problema esté en otra parte del archivo de configuración.

Answer (score 0):

intenta con las siguientes lineas de código

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

error_page 404 /404.html; #aca va tu error personalizado
```

usa sudo `nginx -t` para que te diga si tienes errores antes que reinicies el nginx